# Что будет если будет запущено 2 процеса

Tags: c#, .net

Что произойдет если запустить оба процесса которые описаны ниже:

```
Process[] tasker = Process.GetProcessesByName("dota");
Process[] tasker2 = Process.GetProcessesByName("csgo");
```

если запущен один из этих процессов?

Пробую так:

```
if (tasker.Length == 0 | tasker2.Length == 0)
if (tasker.Length == 0 || tasker2.Length == 0)
if (tasker.Length == 0 && tasker2.Length == 0)
```

Но ничего не работает, а если взять только один,то все ок.

```
if (tasker.Length == 0)
```

Как быть?

Comment: что вы проверить-то пытаетесь? что что-то не запущено? что что-то запущено? что оба процесса запущены?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Как что? В заголовке "если запущено два процесса" -- значит нужно && только `if (tasker.Length != 0 && tasker2.Length != 0)`

Comment: @AK а в теле написано `если запущен один из этих процессов,то` ... так что не ясно....... и вообще, что значит "если запущено два процесса" ? почему это должно значит что нужна проверка на то, что запущено два процесса?

Comment: `if (tasker.Length > 0 && tasker2.Length > 0)`

Comment: @0xdb - вы уверены что заголовок именно такой должен быть?

Comment: @tym32167 Ответы - в ответы :)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский нет, не уверен, поэтому и оставил таким, как был.

Comment: @AK есть, капитан :)

Comment: @0xdb он же другим был) ааа... там другой человек успел нашурундить

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну да, убрал C#, что не так? "если запушено 2 процесса то" - это заголовок?

Comment: @0xdb нет...посмотрите правки. я думал вы поменяли заголовок автора, а оказывается другой. Видимо слияние было.  А у ТС другой заголовок был

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если запущены оба процесса

```
if (tasker.Length > 0 && tasker2.Length > 0)
```

Если запущен хотя бы один процесс

```
if (tasker.Length > 0 || tasker2.Length > 0)
```

Если оба НЕ запущены

```
if (tasker.Length == 0 && tasker2.Length == 0)
```